# jQuery Navigation - Change input of an inputs parent-parent-parent-parent-sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, format

I'm currently looking for advice on some jQuery as I think I'm doing this incorrectly even though I'm getting the result I want.

I want to change the value of an input to the value of the closest input with a class of .milestone when it's changed. The input which I want to change is the holding input and I want it to the equal value of the revised input on change. Below is the HTML which I can't change unfortunately as this is a product.

```
<div class="container area  dform_section_area6">
    <div class="box  box13 two">
        <div class="dform_section_box13">
            <div style="clear: both;" data-type="html" data-name="business_case_approved_pmr" id="dform_widget_html_business_case_approved_pmr" data-active="true" class="dform_widget  dform_widget_type_html dform_widget_business_case_approved_pmr">
                <p>Business Case Approved</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box  box14 two">
        <div class="dform_section_box14">
            <div data-type="date" data-name="bc_approved_planned_pmr" data-active="true" data-agentonly="false" class="container dform_widget  dform_widget_field dform_widget_type_date dform_widget_bc_approved_planned_pmr dform_widget_bc_approved_planned_bc">
                <div>
                    <label for="dform_widget_bc_approved_planned_pmr">Planned</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input id="dform_widget_bc_approved_planned_pmr" type="date" name="bc_approved_planned_pmr" data-mapfrom="bc_approved_planned_bc" class="dform_field_active">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box  box15 two">
        <div class="dform_section_box15">
            <div data-type="select" data-name="bcapproval_on_target" data-active="true" data-agentonly="false" class="container dform_widget  dform_widget_field dform_widget_type_select dform_widget_bcapproval_on_target dform_widget_">
                <div>
                    <label for="dform_widget_bcapproval_on_target">On target?</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select id="dform_widget_bcapproval_on_target" name="bcapproval_on_target" class="dform_field_active">
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="Yes" data-off="bc_approved_revised_pmr">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No" data-on="bc_approved_revised_pmr">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box  box16 two">
        <div class="dform_section_box16">
            <div data-type="date" data-name="bc_approved_revised_pmr" data-active="false" data-agentonly="false" class="container dform_widget milestone mrevise dform_widget_field dform_widget_type_date dform_widget_bc_approved_revised_pmr dform_widget_">
                <div>
                    <label for="dform_widget_bc_approved_revised_pmr">*Revised</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input id="dform_widget_bc_approved_revised_pmr" type="date" name="bc_approved_revised_pmr" class="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box  box17 two">
        <div class="dform_section_box17">
            <div data-type="date" data-name="gate_3_actual1" data-active="true" data-agentonly="false" class="container dform_widget  dform_widget_field dform_widget_type_date dform_widget_gate_3_actual1 dform_widget_">
                <div>
                    <label for="dform_widget_gate_3_actual1">Actual</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input id="dform_widget_gate_3_actual1" type="date" name="gate_3_actual1" class="dform_field_active">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box  box18 last two">
        <div class="dform_section_box18">
            <div data-type="date" data-name="bc_approved_planned_bc" data-active="true" data-agentonly="false" class="container dform_widget param mrevise dform_widget_field dform_widget_type_date dform_widget_bc_approved_planned_bc dform_widget_">
                <div>
                    <label for="dform_widget_bc_approved_planned_bc">holding</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input id="dform_widget_bc_approved_planned_bc" type="date" name="bc_approved_planned_bc" class="dform_field_active">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the jQuery below to find the value of the input I want to update but I can't help but think that there must be a less long winded way to change this. I can't just reference the input's ID as I need to do this for 20+ fields.

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next().next().find('.param').find('input').val()
```

This =

```
<input id="dform_widget_bc_approved_revised_pmr" type="date" name="bc_approved_revised_pmr" class="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closest() method instead and find recursive parent() element and then find child level element for siblings.

```
$(this).closest(".dform_section_area6").find('.param:last input').val()
```

Comment: Unfortunately using that I then have to create one for each dform_section_area and currently there are 20 (dform_section_area1 - dform_section_area20)